# Split Different Separator and Get middle value (DateTime Format)

Tags: javascript, string, variables, split, slice

I want to split this datetime format :

> 2021-07-21T22:24:40+02:00

(+02:00 is a TimeZone)

and get this value :

> 22:24:40

have tried this :

```
var raw_time = "2021-07-21T22:24:40+02:00";
var timewZ = raw_time.split("T").split("+").slice(1,?);`
```

Will definitely appreciate your help :)

Comment: This format is a fixed length, so you can rely on `time.slice(11, 19);`

Comment: ahh never thought it would be that simple. thank you!!

Comment: @Andreasssouwxt do you want to ignore the timezone in the time?

Comment: yeah, just want to get HH:mm:ss